Solution of linear dynamical systems without Fourier transforming.
I'm trying to understand an exercise for my exam of mathematical methods for physics, in which it is asked to find the general expression of the Green function of the following system without using the Fourier transform:
$$
\dot{x} (t) + i x(t) = f(t)
$$
where $x(t)$ is the input and $f(t)$ is the output. By inputting $x(t) = G(t)$ (the Green function indeed), we get:
$$\dot{G}(t) + iG(t) = \delta(t)$$
where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta centred at $0$. The solution provided by my professor is based on computing the Green function for $t<0$ and $t>0$ and then checking what happens in $t=0$; using this method, we get:
$$
\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{ c l }
    t>0, \ \dot{G}(t) + i G(t) = 0 \Rightarrow G(t) = ce^{-it} \\
    t<0, \ \dot{G}(t) + i G(t) = 0 \Rightarrow G(t) = c'e^{-it}
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
What bothers me is that he then says
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} G(t) - \lim_{t\to 0^-} G(t)\equiv G(0^+) - G(0^-) = c - c'=\lambda=1$$
where $\lambda$ is the coefficient of the $\delta(t)$, which is equal to $1$ in this case. I don't understand why $c-c'$ should be equal to the coefficient of the $\delta(t)$.
The exercise ends by observing that $c'=c+1$, hence:
$$
G(t) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{ c l }
    ce^{-it}, &\ t>0 \\
    (c+1) e^{-it}, &\ t<0
  \end{array}
\right.
 = \theta(t) e^{-it} + ce^{-it}$$
This is clear to me; what I don't get is why $c - c' = \lambda$.
Thank you in advance for helping me!

The usual way to derive this jump in the Green's function is by integrating both sides of the differential equation between $-\varepsilon$ and $+\varepsilon$:
$$
\int_{-\varepsilon}^{+\varepsilon}[\dot{G}(t)+iG(t)]\,dt
=\int_{-\varepsilon}^{+\varepsilon}\delta(t)\,dt
\implies G(+\varepsilon)-G(-\varepsilon)
+i\int_{-\varepsilon}^{+\varepsilon}G(t)\,dt=1. \tag{1}
$$
Taking the limit $\varepsilon\to 0^+$, we obtain
$$
G(+0)-G(-0)=1. \tag{2}
$$
Alternatively, we can solve the differential equation directly:
\begin{align}
\dot{G}+iG&=\delta(t) \implies e^{it}(\dot{G}+iG)
=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{it}G)=e^{it}\delta(t) \\
&\implies e^{it}G(t)=\underbrace{e^{it_0}G(t_0)}_{=\,c}
+\int_{t_0}^{t}e^{it'}\delta(t')\,dt' \qquad\qquad[t_0<0]\\
&\implies G(t)=ce^{-it}+\theta(t)e^{-it}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
